# How to implement GoJS Org Chart Editor for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, gojs, orgchart

How to implement GoJS Org Chart Editor for ASP.NET with Database ? I'm just beginner for ASP.NET, any other similar to the Organization Chart as screenshot attached here will also do

[Screenshot of GOJS Org Chart how it looks and how I need for ASP.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsQj9.jpg)

https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html

Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example:
https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS-Alongside-Blazor

GoJS is a user-interface component that normally runs entirely in the browser, so it imposes no requirements on any communications protocols or web servers or databases.

You will want to copy the diagramming code from the Org Chart sample into this file: https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS-Alongside-Blazor/blob/master/GoJSBlazor/wwwroot/js/gojs-scripts.js